# Laravel issues I need assistance

Tags: php, laravel-5

I recently started a laravel project. Every has been all good. But I am having an issue with registration. Whenever I fill in the form fields and hit on register, it gives me an error.

> BadMethodCallException in validator.php Method [validateMatno] does
>   not exist.

(Matno is the name of my form.)

Comment: Show us the validation logic from your registration form.

Comment: We need to see your code, but from the error I can see that you're making a request to a page that's referencing a method in a controller called `validateMatno` and it does not exist. You need to create a method to accept this request.

Answer (score 0):

Your code not attached to this question, but I mean the problem from your validation, so try to remove it and see if it's work, in Laravel, withing validating any request, we use the default validation rules: like required|string|date ... see them [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#available-validation-rules)

if you're using another role without any package included, that will show an ERROR

I mean you can't use this:

```
"your_field" => "matno" // JUST AN EXAMPLE
```